# How to get notified on Azure DevOps PR issue status change

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-code-review

As code reviewer with Azure DevOps you are able to leave feedback that can be marked with such [statuses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops):

```
- Active: Comment is still under review.
- Pending: The issue in this comment will be addressed, but isn't fixed yet.
- Resolved: The issue brought up in this comment has been fixed.
- Won't Fix: The suggestion in the comment is noted, but won't make changes in this pull request to address it.
- Closed: Discussion for this comment is closed.
```

Is that possible to get notified when the status is changed? Right now I can receive notifications on new comments

Comment: Hey deep I thing you can create new notification related to it in project settings.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot get this notification, In the Azure DevOps [default and supported notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-built-in-notifications?view=azure-devops) and [supported event types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-supported-event-types?view=azure-devops) have Changed by, Changes in folder, Code under review, Created by, Event type, Policy Bypass, Repository name, Reviewers, Source branch name, Status, Target branch name, Team project, Vote. And the comment will only Notify you about comments made to a pull request that you created or a discussion you're involved in.

This should be a good improvement, also I have helped you to submit the [relevant suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1124654/add-new-pull-request-notification.html). To receive the notification about it in time, you can vote and follow this suggestion ticket.

Comment: thank you for links. eventually there were similar requests coded because of low popularity. that's why I'm wondering if there is another "correct" approach for this flow

Comment: I have tried web hook and notification, but cannot get notified when the status is changed, we recommend that you follow the suggestion ticket to get the latest news.